# How do I make a python game switch to different .py files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a crappy python game. I want to have separate files for each snake in the game. How do I make each snake have their own file? Also how can I make it create save files and load them? Here's the link to the code on trinket: https://trinket.io/python/47ae4b66c7

Comment: " How do I make each snake have their own file?" It's not clear why you want to do this. See [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at your code (post it here if you want), but to "swap" Python modules with those of similar functionality, you *could* do something like

```
if snake_species == 'cobra':
   from cobra_snake import CobraSnake as Snake
else:
   from viper_snake import ViperSnake as Snake

snake = Snake()
```

This is bad/annoying for a host of reasons. Don't do it.

A less finnicky strategy would be to import all your snakes in different modules, then add them to a single registry you could look through.

```
import cobra_snake
import viper_snake

snake_types = {
    'cobra': cobra_snake.CobraSnake,
    'viper': viper_snake.ViperSnake,
}

# then when you want to use one:
snake = snake_types[snake_species]()
```